# Securing Solr on Tomcat7

Tags: solr, tomcat7

I try to secure my Solr instance but i cant getting it to work. I do everything in the way i saw it in many many tutorials but it seems like solr is ignoring my web.xml.

My Steps:

1: Editing tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>

    <role rolename="solr-role"/>
    <user username="test" password="test" roles="solr-role"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

2: Editing web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Solr Lockdown</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>solr-role</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Solr</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

3: Restart tomcat7

After that i try to access http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/solr/ and i get access without any password prompt.

What is my fault?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but i used the wrong web.xml.
I uses the file stored under `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/solr/WEB_INF/web.xml` but i have to use the file under `/etc/tomcat7/web.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following lines to web.xml secures the admin pages of solr (at least for solr 4.2.1, but that should also work for 4.5.1)

```xml
<security-constraint>
  <!-- This protects your admin interface and grants access to role admin -->
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr admin</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/admin.html</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>solr</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <security-role>
      <role-name>solr</role-name>
  </security-role>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>SOLR Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Comment: Strange... it *is* working for me (just tested the same config on 4.5.0).
Where did you change the web.xml? If you have changed it inside the WAR file, but tomcat already exploded it into a folder - then you will  need to delete the folder, because tomcat may not pick new web.xml from WAR file.

Comment: I use Solr 4.4.0. The web.xml is stored under /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/

Comment: I will try it with the newest version!